# Image next to a Division

Tags: html, css

How can I put an `<img>` next to a `<div>` so the image vertically aligns in the middle?

```
<img src="http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/images/comment-icon.gif"><div style="font:10pt Arial;padding:5px;background-color:#ccc;"><span style="float:right">No. 1</span><span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:10px">John Doe</span><span style="color:#808080">11/14/2010 3:23:44</span></div>
```

I know how to do it using a table:

```
<table style="font:10pt Arial">
<tr>    
<td style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/images/comment-icon.gif"></td>    
<td style="width:100%">
<div style="padding:5px;background-color:#ccc;border-top:1px solid #DEDEDE"><span style="float:right">No. 1</span><span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:10px">John Doe</span><span style="color:#808080">11/14/2010 3:23:44</span></div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I wonder if I could do it without a table.

Thanks in advance!
Rain Lover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest from your example I have a feeling you may be taking slightly the wrong approach for this.

Personally I would attach this icon to the div as a CSS `background-image`. Afterwards, you could apply padding to the left of the div equal to the width of the image (plus a few more pixels for spacing). Then, you will be able to use background-position to do something like this:

```
background-position:0px center;
```

This will give you the higher degree of control that I think you're after.

Comment: The Javascript designers must be Americans, since that's `center` and not `centre`.

Comment: Whoops. I used English, my bad.

Comment: @Frédéric: Sure looks like CSS, not javascript, to me

Comment: Dear Jon, Many thanks for the answer! I wonder if you could provide an embed code as I'm stuck and can't follow your general hints.

Comment: @Rain Lover: http://jsfiddle.net/63S5M/ This was done quickly, but hopefully it should give you a good idea.

Comment: @Jon, I really like your approach to the problem! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

With block elements such as `img` and `div`, you cannot position them vertically in the centre of something without actually having a something (element) to vertically centre them inside of.

Having said that it is still not possible aside from using [some sort of hack](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html). The far simpler method would be to use a `relative` position on one of the elements and offset its position such that it visually creates the same effect, or use a margin/padding to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done the following way. There is no easy way to center unless you have it inside an element with a specific height and can be played with. This can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/CvpUB/1/

```
<div>
    <img src="http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/images/comment-icon.gif" style="float:left; padding:5px;">
    <div style="font:10pt Arial;padding:5px;background-color:#ccc;">
        <span style="float:right">No. 1</span>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right:10px;float:left;">John Doe</span>
        <span style="color:#808080">11/14/2010 3:23:44</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

now if you increase your font size, you will have to change padding to:

```
 padding-top: 5px; // change in sync with bottom to center in text
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
```